# Unable to build Allegro C++ program in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c, allegro, allegro5

I am a complete beginner in allegro and i just installed allegro correctly and this is my code(my first code):

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_font.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_ttf.h>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;
    if (!al_init())
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(display,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   "Could not initialize allegro 5",
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL);
    }
    display = al_create_display(800, 600);
    if (!display)
    {
        al_show_native_message_box(display,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   "Could not initialize allegro WINDOW ",
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL);
    }
    al_rest(5.0);
    al_destroy_display(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Now this is what the build log displays:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Allegro_intro, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>c:\users\krish\desktop\projects\allegro_intro\allegro_intro\main.cpp(11): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'display' used
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in font.obj
1>C:\Users\krish\Desktop\Projects\Allegro_intro\Debug\Allegro_intro.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And then there is a dialog box that says " UNABLE TO START PROGRAM... The system cannot find the file specified".
Please tell me what to do about this

Comment: Can't help with the second error, partly because I don't know allegro at all, but but the first error is because `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;` doesn't point `display` at anything before using it. There should be some initialization function you can call to get a valid `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY` object you can use in `al_show_native_message_box`. I recommend consulting the documentation or tutorial you have been following. It looks like you may have missed a line.

Comment: Your Main method is declared twice. Search for another Main method, and delete one of them

Comment: https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_create_display looks like a good candidate for what you are missing.

Comment: It looks like you have another `main` function in `font.cpp` You can't have two.

Comment: That's the [One Definition Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), or in a more dramatic presentation, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqcLjcSloXs.

Answer (score 0):

display is uninitialized when passed to the first call to al_show_native_message_box, which will result in random memory access. If you need to call al_show_native_message_box before al_init and al_create_display are called, pass NULL for the display parameter.

Always initialize your variables. ;)

Comment: yes, ok, but that is not the problem here: he has a compilation a error